# Spring Authorization Sever Oauth 2.0 - Real Deployment Issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

So, currently i have a front-end server, a bff( back end for front end server also named gateway ) , a resource server and the auth server.

The BFF is configured as java spring boot with spring oauth 2 client dependency.

Every oauth flow is done trought the BFF server. This BFF redirects to the front end user ( browser ) auth-server uris and endpoints . And after auth is successful then it stores the access and refresh token and then it fetches resources from the resource server.

On local everything is working, i have set up a custom domain "custom-domain" linked up to 127.0.0.1 in order to avoid localhost because of that redirect uri issue that doesn't allow you to specify "localhost" as a redirect uri.

Also, the BFF service has a context-path of /client in order to be different than the auth server and not have a clash on the cookies ( this is at least what i read idk if it is necesarily corect )

Now, i'm trying to deploy them in a kubernetes cluster on my local docker. All 4 services would be in the same cluster, and every one of them would be ClusterIp. Also a Ingress would be availbale to route traffic in the cluster.

I also have two custom domains:

1. api.custom.com that links to the gateway
2. auth.custom.com that links to the auth server

However, the issuer-uri from the gateway ( the address to comunicate with the auth server inside the cluster) is set to auth-server ( kubernetes label) . So there are two communications:

1. FE - Auth server when bff sends the redirect uris ( auth.custom.com )
2. BFF - AUTH server for direct communcation ( auth-server)

And unfortunately, there is a issue, first of all when the auth.custom.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type/* will reach the auth server, an Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter will apper in the logs , unlike on the local logs where Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (8/20) is taking place.

Can session/domain issues/topics be explained somewhow regarding the authorization server as well as kubernetes related stuff?

For example, can an auth server be inside the same cluster? should it be cluster, node port , load balancer? What session/domain issues can prevent auth workflow from working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [BFF tutorial on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2) is [deployed](https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/ui/) to a K8s cluster and one of the 3 authorization servers (a Keycloak instance) is hosted by the same cluster.

Authorisation server and BFF are configured completely separately: different namespaces, different ingresses and even different sub-domains (respectively `oidc.c4-soft.com` and `bff.demo.c4-soft.com`).

Also, the BFF is implemented with `spring-cloud-gateway` configured as OAuth2 client and with `TokenRelay` filter (like you are doing, apparently).

The ingresses are used only to route `oidc.c4-soft.com` to the Keycloak service and `bff.demo.c4-soft.com` to the BFF one. What to do with a request based on its path is determined with `spring-cloud-gateway` [configuration](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/ed1e8da796dafd667ae5f308d05d62726066449c/samples/tutorials/bff/gateway/src/main/resources/application.yml#L64), just as when running outside of K8s.

Both resource servers (REST APIs) and front-end (Angular app) are served (and routed) based on a path prefix on the same host (and port), which greatly simplifies CORS configuration: requests have the same origin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped understand a lot of additional concepts.

But i'm interested in understading this session/cookie aspect, especially when using BFF and having auth server on different domain or subdomains.

Let's say BFF is on bff.com and auth on auth.com , so different domains.

If BFF is handling the get user info for you, front end will call bff ( because it sees bff.com it will send the cookie for this domain ) , and then BFF call auth with of course, the wrong cookie, since auth is expecting another session id , and that is the cookie from the browser for auth.

Comment: Or, are you just redirecting the auth address to the front end?

Comment: This is a different question which has nothing to do with K8s... Of course, BFF and authorization server have different session cookies: they are completely separate processes with separate sessions. When using authorization-code flow, the BFF redirects the user (front-end) to the Authorization server, with an authorization code URI pointing to itself (BFF), like any OAuth2 client would. The browser send this requests with, off course, the auth server session cookie to the auth server authorization endpoint, and BFF one to the BFF authorization-code endpoint.

Comment: The request from the OAuth2 client (BFF) to the auth server endpoint is done without session (it has the authorization code already)